# How to add a new item in the drop down list of a field using HTML and PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a webpage which has a drop down of countries, and i want to add an option that if the user does not find his/her country then he can add his country name and this country name should be added to the database table in which all names of countries are stored.

```html
<?php
     include("config.php");
     $query="select name from country";
     $result=mysqli_query($dbconn,$query);

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>REGISTRATION</title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="registration.php" method="POST">
            <br>
            name : <input type="text" name="name"/> 
            <br>
            age : <input type="number" name="age" min="10"/>
            <br>
            gender :  
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
            <br>
            Email ID : <input type="email" name="email"/>
            <br>
            COUNTRY : 
            <select>
                   <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;?>
                   <option><?php echo $row[name];?></option>
                   <?php endwhile;?>        
            </select>
            <br>
            username : <input type="text" name="username"/>
            <br>
            password : <input type="password" name="password1"/>
            <br>
            re-enter password : <input type="password" name="password2"/>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, what is your problem ?

Comment: Just get a list of ALL countries and display that list.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3

Comment: if suppose i have 5 countries A B C D and user is from country E so he should be able to enter that country name and as he submits the form E has to be stored in my country table.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error here use quotes

```
 <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):?>
<option><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
<?php endwhile;?>
```